# Sequelize: getting all passed data in create/update

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am passing a plain object to my UserModel as follows:

```
let user = await User.create(
    {email: 'foo@bar.org', password: 'foo', passwordConfirm: 'foo'}
);
```

Bear in mind that the actual UserModel has two attributes:

1. `email`
2. `passwordHash`

Now, inside `beforeValidate`, I want to compare `password` and `passwordConfirm` for equality and in `beforeCreate`, I want to `bcrypt` `password` to `passwordHash`.

Unfortunately, by the time the entity/data reaches the callback, it has already been cleaned and stripped of any properties that are not part of the model definition.  This means, I will only receive `email` in the instance data.

I don't want to do the equality comparison & hashing outside of the instance. Is there any way to neatly have this logic happen inside the entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming there is a typo in your question and you want to first compare `password` and `passwordConfirm` (not `passwordHash`) before creating the hash from the password.

For the former I would recommend moving it outside of Sequelize, but if you *do* want to pass it in you should create two new fields of type `VIRTUAL` to hold the `password` and `passwordConfirm` without committing them to the database (or even creating a column), and then use a validator to make sure they match. Assuming the validation passes, you would then create the `passwordHash` from the `password` value.

```js
passwordHash: {
  // this will be persisted to the database
  type: DataTypes.STRING(),
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    notEmpty: true,
  },
},
passwordConfirm: {
  // VIRTUAL, not committed
  type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL(),
},
password: {
  // VIRTUAL, not committed
  type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL(),
  // when the field is set, use it to generate a hash
  set: function hashPassword(val) {
    // use the synchronous version, second arg is salt rounds
    this.setDataValue('passwordHash', bcrypt.hashSync(val, 10);
  },
  validate: {
    notEmpty: true,
    // validate that the password and confirmation match
    isConfirmed() {
      return this.password === this.passwordConfirm;
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: This is a great solution - thank you very much.  I like the solution with the `VIRTUAL` data type and being able to use Sequelize's built-in validation. And you're right - it was a type which I have now fixed. Ta!